# Single UIViewcontroller, how to switch among multiple xibs?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have a subclass of `UIViewController`:

```
 @interface KBViewController : UIViewController
```

with multiple `xib`s, for example, one is a `Qwerty` and the another is `Dvorak` layout:

```
 KBViewControllerQuerty~iphone.xib
 KBViewControllerDvorak~iphone.xib
```

So when the user click a button, `Qwerty` is switch to `Dvorak`. As you may see, the code logic is identical for both keyboard layouts. What I need is to reload the `view` with another `xib`.

Hopefully, all the buttons in the `Dvorak` `xib` will be hooks to the responding `IBOutlet`s in `KBViewController`.

What is the right way to switch between the two `xib`s?

Comment: do you mean re-initialize the view controller with different nib? i don't think it is possible. try replace the old one with new one

Comment: I'd like to replace `self.view` in `KBViewController` and hopefully all the buttons in the `Dvorak` xib will be hooked to the responding `IBOutlet`s of `KBViewController`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All Nibs has the designated `File's Owner`. IBOutlet and IBAction linking is done based upon the `File's Owner`. So you could define a view controller and two Nibs, with each Nib file's `File's Owner` set to the defined view controller.

That is, if you set `File's Owner` of all KBViewController*.xib files to KBViewController and have a KBViewController object somewhere you could load the KBViewController*.xib you want by `initWithNibNamed` method (recreate the view controller)

If you should maintain the same KBViewController object all along, you could create a KBViewController object without Nib. In KBViewController.m, implement `loadView` and manually load the UIView object with `-[NSBundle loadNibNamed]` method (load and change self.view programmatically).

```
UIView *someView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SomeNibFile"
                                                  owner:self
                                                options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
self.view = someView;
```

Note `owner:self` in above code. It must match with `File's Owner` of the @"SomeNibFile".

To change already loaded view:

```
id superview = self.view.superview;
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
UIView *someView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SomeNibFile"
                                                  owner:self
                                                options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
self.view = someView;
[superview addSubview:self.view];
```

More detailed explanation:
[Resource Programming Guide - Loading Nib Files Programmatically](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW10)

Answer (score 0):

You can load your nib file manually and change the `view` attribute of your view controller or change any view you want, respectively.

```
    UIView *someView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SomeNibFile"
                                                      owner:self
                                                    options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

The `objectAtIndex:0` is only correct when there is only one `UIView` root object in your nib file

After loading your view, you can set

```
self.view = someView;
```

Of course, if you have a subview in your view controller, then you can change that, too.

Comment: does this hook the controls in the new nib to the `IBOutlet`s of the current view controller?

Comment: No, I don't think so, but it would be possible to write a `UIView` subclass for your KBViews and link each view in your xib files to this subclass. Then, you have a `UIViewController` with a view of your subclassed `UIView` and the controls are hooked to the subclass. When both of your xib files have the same hooks to your `UIView` subclass then it should work like you want.