# Wrong orientation of view after xib file changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xib

In my design, there is a button to change the xib file. after google a thousand times, I found the solution as showed below:

```
- (IBAction)changeButtonDidPress:(id)sender
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (self.xibChanged) {
            NSArray *nibObjs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyViewController" owner:self options:nil];
            UIView *aView = [nibObjs objectAtIndex:0];
            self.view = aView;
            self.xibChanged = NO;
        } else {
            NSArray *nibObjs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomViewController" owner:self options:nil];
            UIView *aView = [nibObjs objectAtIndex:0];
            self.view = aView;
            self.xibChanged = YES;
        }
   });
}
```

But, there's a problem: the orientation of the view after changing xib file is wrong (always portrait, no matter how I set the xib file)!

**ps: I also tried:**

1) [Change view in one XIB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16402602/change-view-in-one-xib), worked well, but it means I need to create a new controller, what I never wanted!

2) [Single UIViewcontroller, how to switch among multiple xibs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496901/single-uiviewcontroller-how-to-switch-among-multiple-xibs), not worked at all, and some buttons lost in the new view!

So, I post this issue, did someone run into the similar issue? any good ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, after a thousand times of retrying, I just found a workaround: `rotate your new view that has wrong orientation`.

At the first beginning, please be sure **the xibs using autosizing**, otherwise you should do more hard work!

Then add this method to your viewcontroller:

```
- (void)rotateUIView:(UIView *)aView toInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Get data of rotating view
    CGRect bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat angle = 0.0f, width = 0.0f, height = 0.0f;
    switch (interfaceOrientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            angle = M_PI;
            width = bounds.size.width;
            height = bounds.size.height;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            angle = -M_PI_2;
            height = bounds.size.width;
            width = bounds.size.height;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            angle = M_PI_2;
            height = bounds.size.width;
            width = bounds.size.height;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        default:
            return;
    }

    // Rotate the view
    [aView setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
    [aView setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(aView.transform, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle))];
}
```

Call this method after changing xib file, as follows:

```
[self rotateUIView:self.view toInterfaceOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]];
```

Then the orientation of the view is all right! Hope this can solve your problem too!